# Skeleton tracking in ROS is not working

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I am using ROS Fuerte+Ubuntu 12.04.
In skeleton tracking, I downloaded the pi_tracker and skeleton_markers package. Then I run the following commands:

```
 cd ~/ros_workspace/
 svn checkout http:_//pi-robot-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pi_tracker;
 svn checkout http:_//pi-robot-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/skeleton_markers;
 cd pi_tracker/;
 rosmake/;
 cd ../skeleton_markers/
 rosmake/
```

I didn't get any error.
Then I run roscore command in one terminal

In another terminal, I run
`roslaunch skeleton_markers markers_from_tf.launch`, I was getting error
How to solve

> 'No such file or directory: u'/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/launch/openni_node.launch'?

I modified these errors with the help given in the following link :

http://answers.ros.org/question/43173/how-to-solve-no-such-file-or-directory-uoptrosfuertestacksopenni_cameralaunchopenni_nodelaunch/

but again when I run
`roslaunch skeleton_markers markers_from_tf.launch`, it is showing the following error

> [openni_tracker-22] process has died [pid 21752, exit code 18, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_tracker/bin/openni_tracker __name:=openni_tracker __log:=/home/jaya/.ros/log/851ade76-8d44-11e2-a6f7-a088b43d45c4/openni_tracker-22.log].
> log file: /home/jaya/.ros/log/851ade76-8d44-11e2-a6f7-a088b43d45c4/openni_tracker-22*.log

Please help me. How could I do skeleton tracking in ROS fuerte+ubuntu 12.04.

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58410/skeleton-tracking-in-ros-is-not-working./) by [jaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/4432/jaya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/4432/jaya/) on 2013-03-17**:
just remove the underscore after the http in every URL. I don't have enough karma points to publish links :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you are having issues because you don't have the openni_kinect
*http:*//www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect stack installed. You might want to do that first. Also just a small note if you are having other issues you might need to download the Openni Nite 1.5.2 SDK.

---

Originally posted by [Rookdroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/4073/rookdroid/) with karma: 76 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2013-03-18**:
@Rookdroid is possibly right about having to install Nite 1.5.2. See [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/42654/openninite-incompatible-in-fuertegroovy-on-precise/)

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-03-18**:
Please remember, that just after download NITE 1.5.2, FIRST run the uninstall script, then the install script. Some weird behaviors sometimes appears if you forget to do so.

**Comment by [jaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/4432/jaya/) on 2013-03-19**:
In ROS, when I have installed ROS(Fuerte) in ubuntu 12.04 using sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full then all the packages supported by ROS should installed. IT is showing there is a package Openni_kinect and openni_nite ,but I am not able to do skeleton tracking. :-( Please help me

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-03-19**:
No. It installs only some mnadatory packages. Not all packages (hopefully !). You have to do a "sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-openni*" to install all openni related packages, and also go to the NITE page, and install NITE 1.5.2...